# How to get the localized version of the months from angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, localization

How would I get a localized version of every month in angularjs in an array?  I know how to localize a single date using the format options, but in this case I want all of the months.  Basically, this is going to be bound to a select that the user can than choose a month.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I m guessing that your page will be entirely localized in a given language and that you will add the proper angular-locale file as such :

```
<script src="http://.../angular-locale_xx-xx.js"></script> // ex: angular-locale_fr-fr.js
```

If this is the case you can simply access all the months as an array like that :

```
function Controller($scope, $locale) { //inject the $locale service
  var datetime = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS; //get date and time formats 
  $scope.months = datetime.MONTH; //access localized months
}
```

You can see a working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UtQHTy0eSl7ly4cMfEWi?p=preview)